# Extend (android.app.notification.extender) in builder cannot be applied to (android.support.v4.app.notificationcompat.wearableextender)

Tags: android

I'm trying to issue a notification on android watch, but get this error. I think it is something wrong with imports, but I could not manage to organise them.

Here are my imports :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.RemoteInput;
import android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
```

Notification:

```
 NotificationCompat.WearableExtender wearableExtender = new NotificationCompat.WearableExtender()
            .addAction(confirmAction)
            .addAction(replyAction);

 Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle(ItemName)
            .setContentText(ItemQty)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_task)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .extend(wearableExtender)
            .build();
```

My minSDK is 18 and compile version is 22.

Any thoughts on what's the issue?
If you need any additional code, please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured that I just  had to edit my notification as follows:

```
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
```

since I'm using appcompat

Comment: I did the above but there is an error with `this`: `Builder cannot be applied to ` the class that extends `BrocastReceiver`